# How to concatenate multiple files created by for loops

Tags: bash, shell

I have multiple files named ./bin.1.fa, ./bin.2.fa, ... .
I would like to edit these files and then concatenate the outcomes with for loops.
The code I've tried is :

```
for file in Metabat/bins.*.fa; 
do
stub=${file%.fa}
stub2=${file#Metabat\/bins.}
grep '^>' $file | cut -c 2- | sed "s/$/$stub2/" 
done
```

( I selected lines starting with > and then cut out the first character > and then concatenated 1 at the end)
I would like to use >> to concatenate, but how can I do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about:

```
A=1; for file in  Metabat/bins.*.fa; do grep '^>' $file | cut -c 2- | sed "s/$/$A/"; let A=$A+1; done > concatenated_file
```

Comment: Hi @OznOg, this is nice, but actually, I need to add the bin number with sed. I need to append 1 to every end of lines of files created by 1, and append 2 with files created by 2 at the second column and so on. Is there a way to do this also?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @OznOg, I got an idea and broke the code into two steps.

```
for file in Metabat/bins.*.fa;  do stub=${file%.fa}; stub2=${stub#Metabat\/bins.}; grep '^>' $file | cut -c 2- | sed "s/$/,$stub2/" > Metabat/edit_$stub2 ; done
```

And then I put

```
cat Metabat/edit* > Metabat/edit0
```